# Get Day of week and Month name from DatePicker

Tags: android, datepicker, timepicker

I am getting date and time from `DatePicker` and `TimePicker` like:

```
int dateofmonth = date.getDayOfMonth();
int month = date.getMonth() + 1;
int year = date.getYear();
int hour = time.getCurrentHour();
int minutes = time.getCurrentMinute();
```

But i want date and time like this format:

> **Friday, December 14,2012 - 4:30 PM**.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

formate  it as you want ....

```
public void SetMyCustomFormat()
{
   // Set the Format type and the CustomFormat string.
   dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
   dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "put your formate here ";
}
```

for more help

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat.aspx

Comment: Why did you gave him MSDN references if he asked about Android?!

Comment: sorry sir i do not notice at that  time when i put my answer ... i just saw date time picker question and code

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `SimpleDateFormat`, see [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)
Under the examples section is a date that represents your required format.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is formatting a `Date` object in the current locale, you can use [`DateFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html#getDateTimeInstance%28%29):

```
Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
date.set(Calendar.YEAR, picker.getYear());
...
String str = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(date);
```

The method `getDateTimeInstance()` returns the preferred display for the current locale, which is desirable to internationalize your application because different locales have different preferences for the order of the components. For example:

```txt
US:    Friday, December 14,2012 - 4:30 PM
Italy: Venerdì 14 Dicembre 2012, 16:30
```

Comment: @WasimAkram Sorry, anyway you can just construct a [`Calendar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) and then passing the calendar to the `format()` method. But how do you get the time (4:30PM)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Date Object first from Calendar, you can do as below:

```
Calendar cal= Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(new Date());
int dateofmonth = date.getDayOfMonth();
int month = date.getMonth();
int year = date.getYear();
cal.set(dateofmonth, month, year);
```

Now create a SimpleDateFormat object, with the format, you desire, and format date with that format, by

```
String formattedDate=simpleDateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
```